# When using suneditor toolbarContainer property, why is the toolbar layout messed up and the icons huge?

Tags: reactjs, suneditor

When using a custom toolbar container for suneditor, the layout is messed up.

```
<div id='someContainer' />
```

...

```
    <SunEditor
       setOptions={{
         toolbarContainer : '#someContainer'
       }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

The toolbar css assumes the it inside a container with class name 'sun-editor'. So ensure the custom container includes the 'sun-editor' class name.

```
<div id='someContainer' class='sun-editor' />
```